# How do I compile a smart contract written in pure yul using Foundry?

Tags: solidity, foundry, yul

Basically I want to do a written tutorial on how to compile and deploy this CREATE2 proxy contract, written in pure Yul.

https://github.com/Arachnid/deterministic-deployment-proxy/blob/master/source/deterministic-deployment-proxy.yul

This is what Foundry uses by default to deploy contracts using CREATE2.

Ironically I can't figure out a way to compile and deploy this very contract from within Foundry.

Answer (score 0):

there is no built-in method as far as I'm aware. you can see an example here:
https://github.com/CodeForcer/foundry-yul

Answer (score 0):

You can install [this repo](https://github.com/crystalbit/deploy-yul) to foundry and use YulCompiler contract to test and deploy from your project. There is also example usage

Comment: Thank you bro. I'll look into this. The existing yul deployer implementations did not work for me, I don't know if I was wrong or they were wrong.

I was trying to do a CREATE2 implementation in pure Yul, but just couldn't figure out how to make everything work with Foundry.

I was trying to write an article for the foundry book.
The article is merged now though, and I stuck to the original Solidity implementation.

https://book.getfoundry.sh/tutorials/create2-tutorial

Comment: Nice article, my contributions to foundry book are only fixing typos :D
I improved and fixed YulDeployer in the repo - added vm.broadcast instruction (it wasn't there, so it was suitable for tests only) and changed solc argument for yul compiling - it changed over time there

Comment: Haha, this was a lot of hard work. I managed to put in a bunch of assembly instead of pure yul. It was a privilege to contribute to the book with a full tutorial.

Hopefully this also helps me land a job lol. Should look good on my CV.